# Read 2d Array and Transpose

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, transpose

So the purpose of this code is to read a 2d array from a file and transpose it. I know the transpose portion works but I am having trouble reading the array from the file. I continue to get an array out of bounds error. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Here is the code and the data file is at the bottom.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class prog464d{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    final int ROWS = 5;
    final int COLS = 5;

    int[][] nums = new int[ROWS][COLS];
    // this is used only in java 7 (not java 6)
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("prog464adat.txt"))) {
        int row = -1; // since we're incrementing row at the start of the loop
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            row++;
            String[] line = input.nextLine().split("\t");
            for(int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
                try {
                    nums[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(line[col]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // do something here
        System.out.print("File not found!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nums[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(nums[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n\n matrix transpose:\n");
    // transpose
    if (nums.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums[0].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(nums[j][i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Data file:

```
45 67 89 12 -3
-3 -6 -7 -4 -9
96 81 -8 52 12
14 -7 72 29 -1
19 43 28 63 87
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? So we know what line causes the error.

Comment: After `++row` put `System.out.println(row);` or (even better) run your code under debugger and examine value of `row`.

Comment: After row++ the value of row is showing as 0

Comment: Always zero? Are you sure?

Comment: if the input textfile ends with a new line, you will be setting the row index > ROWS after reading the fifth line; the following split will return String[1] and line[col] will go out of bounds for col == 1 (it would be much easier for you to run the debugger than for us to guess)

Comment: At the line nums[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(line[col]); I keep getting an array out of bounds error

Comment: are you sure the content is split by tab(\t) not space in your file? It is space from the data which you have paste in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing split on read line from the file using \t but actually i copied your data file and checked it is having only space not \t.

so replace this line

```
 String[] line = input.nextLine().split("\t");
```

to

```
 String[] line = input.nextLine().split(" ");
```

when we put `split` based on `\t` then `line` variable gets complete first line of a file as there is no `tab` in your data file.

so `line` becomes `45 67 89 12 -3`

so  `nums[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(line[col]);` line is doing parsing of integer but

actual `line` is `45 67 89 12 -3` and it has spaces , so  it will throw `number format exception`.

since it is handled using `catch` block it goes to next exception

```
Array index bound exception
```

as you are trying to access `array` but no `element` in it because of `Number format exception.`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Scanner class, use BufferReader class to read a file line by line.  When you read each line, save it into Array  or ArrayList of int. When you read the whole file, convert Array or ArrayList to 2D array.

For example:

Reading a file line by line and save each line into an array or arrayList

```
File file = new File(filename);
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line = buffReader.readLine();
    while(line!=null){
       lines.add(line);
       line = buffReader.readLine();

    }
```

convert array or arraylist to 2D dimensional array